# Need help Can I use an excel formula to extract the link location

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need help Can I use an excel formula to extract the link location of a hyperlink which has been generated by using concatenation with url + numbers in a cell? I need the exact link in the Link column
[image]

Comment: If you just need the hyperlink you may be able to use`=formulatext()` and do some text manipulation from there.

Comment: Hi @Nilendu Bhattcharjee, what exactly you want as an output, just [edit] your post & add some screen shot, also how many records the Tempalate Sheet does have?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the hyperlink and send parts from the beginning and end like:

```
="https://wherever.com/send?..."&(C2+D2)&... Concatenate(blah blah,Templates!A:B,2,0)))
```

Note how I removed the hyperlink function and the second parameter, the ",Send" at the end?  Concatenate is basically just the same as &.  The result of your formula will then just be the url without the displayed Send part.

Comment: Hi @Bart Humphries, your formula should have an array (CSE) formula and what about Vlookup ,, check OP's link and the formula used!! Template Sheet should have more than one record !!

Comment: I agree with Bart Humphries. It is hard to extract link location from "Send" column  directly, use the part formula of combining the required characters to get the link address is easier.

Comment: Thanks, Emily. Rajesh, just put the formula in the top row, highlight it and everything below it then got Ctrl+D to copy that formula through all the other rows. There's no reason to use an array formula or VLookUp here.